# Calculating number of days that occur between two Dates

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, timespan

I'm looking for the most succinct solution to the following problem in JavaScript:

I want to determine the number of days that occur between two Dates in JavaScript. I am not looking for the date difference in Days, for example:

Date 1: June 26th 2012 11:05 PM

Date 2: June 27th 2012 12:15 AM

I was using the the following line of code:

```
var days = Math.ceil((date2 - date1) / 86400000);
```

My result is 1, I want it to be 2 (counting June 26th and June 27th)

Comment: what if date2 < date1? always assume positive result?

Comment: @Sebas In my case I will always assume a positive result.

Comment: Hmm I'm really confused, basically you only want the difference between the 2 numbers representing the day of month of 2 given dates? so the difference goes from 1 to 31, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the time portion of the date and then do the date subtraction. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ5Rd/) or the snippet below.

```
var d1 = new Date('June 26th 2012 11:05 PM'.replace('th',''));
var d2 = new Date('June 27th 2012 12:15 AM'.replace('th',''));

// remove the time portion, set the dates to midnight
d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var diff = Math.ceil((d2 - d1) / 86400000) + 1;

console.log(diff);
```

​

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it, I was trying to see if there was another way using dates with time so that I could avoid creating two temporary date objects for the calculation. But this works...thank you.

Comment: Its still incorrect :)

You should do `Math.abs()` . Interchange the `d1` and `d2` and you will get 0 as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Set the hours, minutes, seconds, and miliseconds to all be zero.  Now you have two dates with the same time on them.  Now you can do that operation the way you have been doing it and get the right answer.